# Tags: setup and set-up

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Is it necessary to have both `setup` and `set-up` tags? I think if there was only one, people would choose it when the autocomplete pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed.

I have removed [set-up](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/set-up) from the 3 questions it was on, and also suggested it as a synonym of [setup](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/setup)